# Data Science and Data Lake Use Case Recommendations

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to connect and ingest raw data files from various services that my business uses to see how we can improve our customer experience.

Internal Data

- Location information based on delivery updates and gps units on transportation devices
- Service and repair information on unique transportation units (varying 1000 at a time)
- 4 main WANS and ~40k usernames

External Data

- Transportation part suppliers
- Finance and expense reporting for transportation devices and usernames

Most of the information can be avro, json, xml and csv information

I have began setting up the export of this data from the 5 separate services generating the information, and have found Fivetran to be very helpful. What have you used for building your main analytics, that I only want to give access to a few analysts on my team?

Comment: This question is a bit broad. I think everyone will have a very generalized different story to share for Snowflake migration, ETL providers and experiences. Can you provide a bit more specific context on exactly what recommendations you are looking for? What issue are you trying to resolve or coming across when ingesting data files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** the most appropriate answer at this junction would be to point you in the direction of our "Data Piplelines" document, which can be found at this link:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-pipelines-intro.html

The workflow and data loading framework documented there is robust, and can get you heading in the right direction.